# github apit get commit info related to specific file

Tags: github, github-api

how do I get the most recent commit containing a specific file? I am currently retrieving all the files from a specific directory in my repo like so

```
https://api.github.com/repos/' + this.fullRepoUrl + '/contents' + this.path
```

which returns  a series of objects that look like this

```
{
    "name": "preview-whats-to-come.md",
    "path": "posts/preview-whats-to-come.md",
    "sha": "08bf61b7b1a8895cd1415f93f40315f4c5ef8bf9",
    "size": 1861,
    "url":       "https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/contents/posts/preview-whats-to-come.md?ref=master",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/user/repo/blob/master/posts/preview-whats-to-come.md",
    "git_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/git/blobs/08bf61b7b1a8895cd1415f93f40315f4c5ef8bf9",
    "download_url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/posts/preview-whats-to-come.md",
    "type": "file",
    "_links": {
        "self": "https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/contents/posts/preview-whats-to-come.md?ref=master",
        "git": "https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/git/blobs/08bf61b7b1a8895cd1415f93f40315f4c5ef8bf9",
        "html": "https://github.com/user/repo/blob/master/posts/preview-whats-to-come.md"
}
```

}

I thought of using the sha and pulling in a commit based on that but its not the sha for the most recent commit

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `/contents`, you want the [`/commits`](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/) endpoint. That gives you a list of commits made to the repository (just like `git log`), and accepts a `path` parameter that limits the response to commits touching one file. If you also set the `per_page` parameter, you can further limit it to only the most recent commit. For example,

https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/commits?path=README.md&per_page=1

```
[
  {
    "sha": "658915fa87e88ac11cd6211fcceca3df49eb650f",
    "commit": {
      "message": "Added a link to the releases page in the readme\n\nOctokit uses Github releases to document changes in each release, rather than a changelog file. To avoid confusion, I've added a link to the releases page under the \"Versioning\" section.\n\nThis fixes #639",
      "tree": {
        "sha": "5721d4c257226c77799b232ae5293fd1a0d77aaa",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/git/trees/5721d4c257226c77799b232ae5293fd1a0d77aaa"
      },
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/git/commits/658915fa87e88ac11cd6211fcceca3df49eb650f",
      "comment_count": 0
    },
    "parents": [
      {
        "sha": "615f96a7c06c32e76e1768d29ef0b40ec53da57d",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/commits/615f96a7c06c32e76e1768d29ef0b40ec53da57d",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/commit/615f96a7c06c32e76e1768d29ef0b40ec53da57d"
      }
    ]
    ...snip...
  }
]
```

The top-level `sha` field (658915f) is the commit hash, and matches what's visible at the top of [the README.md page](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/master/README.md) on GitHub (the pasted one may be out of date - try the API link for the current state).