# Why is the response empty when retrieving Github commit info with GraphQL (API V4)?

Tags: github, graphql

with **GraphQL API v4**, I want to fetch commit infos (such as committer, committedDate ) on a file under designated release tag. But unfortunately, below script, I always get blank result with no errors. Nowadays, github cannot get commit info via GraphQL?

```
{'query': 'query($org_name: String!, $resp_name: String!){
             repository(owner: $org_name name: $resp_name){
                    object(expression: "bgi4004-ios-v1.0:proj.ios_mac/AppConfig.plist"){
                                                                                ... on Commit{
                                                                                       committer{
                                                                                                date
                                                                                                user{
                                                                                                     name
                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                 }
                                                                                                }
                                                                                    id
                                                                                             }
                                                                                       }
                                                          }
                                                     }', 
 'variables': {"org_name": "gz-project",
           "resp_name": "bgi4004-unity-cs"}'
}
```

**Response:**

```
{u'data': {u'repository': {u'object': {}}}}
```

**Reference**

https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.13/v4/object/repository/

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing trying to retrieve commitComments (either from User or Repository). Would love to know the answer.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33977354/github-apit-get-commit-info-related-to-specific-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33977354/github-apit-get-commit-info-related-to-specific-file)
eh, sounds like api also not easy to work.